# Switching from Intel to AMD CPU on AWS - anything I need to do?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, aws, amd-processor

I switched my Ubuntu 18.04 AWS instance to run on an AMD processor instead of Intel, and things seem to be working fine, but I was wondering if there were any gotchas I should be aware of.

For example, are there any new packages I need to install, for example packages for AMD microcode updates instead of the Intel ones?

For `apt` packages I've installed, I know the target is amd64 for both Intel and AMD chips, but does the installation detect which processor is being used and optimize for one or the other?

Am I better off doing a clean re-install from a blank instance for the above reasons, or any other reasons?

Comment: Nothing is needed. If some software is optimized for some CPU it will detect the CPU by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do a clean install, remove packages, etc. You don't need to do anything really. amd64 is referring to the x86_64 [(amd64)(64-bit)] architecture, which is supported by all chips from AMD starting from the Athlon 64 series and Intel starting from the Intel Xeon codename `Nocona` in June of 2004. Intel dubbed their implementation of 64-bit operation `intel64`. Any package or piece of software that is written for amd64 CPUs will be supported by these aforementioned chips or newer. The amd64 architecture is also backwards-compatible with 32-bit applications and pieces of software (x86).